# Overlay two Silverlight apps

Tags: silverlight, popup

I was wondering if it is possible to have two Silverlight apps overlway each other.
What I would like to do is have SilverlightApp1 take the whole browser window, then SilverlightApp2 show up as a popup in center of window as modal with transparent background. SilverlightApp2 would take up all window space too (to act as modal and block access to SilverlightApp1), but since the background is transparent it would act as modal and only have the main container element accessible.

Is this possible?

I was kind able to achieve this but not the transparency part of it...

I know there are easier solutions for this, but I am working inside an existing Silverlight application (which is SilverlightApp1 above) where I don't have the ability to modify much, but the HTML containing the app.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make a modal javascript window which overlays the div of SilverlightApp1 and place SilverlightApp2 on it. Maybe you should make SilverlightApp2 not to take up all window space and make the transparent/modal part with a div.

I think this could work.

Comment: I tried that already and the problem is that SilverlightApp1 is always on top of the modal div. This is because SilverlightApp1 is set to windowless=false (I can't change that). So in this scenario I can see SilverlightApp2 in the center but I am still able to click around and get to SilverlightApp1 ...